# nexAll() / prevAll() and condition with hasClass()

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner with jQuery (and I have also a poor english :p )

I have a problem using the `prevAll()` / `nextAll()` jQuery functions.

Here's my HTML code :

```
<div id="zone-presentation">
    <ul id="nav-pres">
        <li>
            <a class="navigation-pres on" id="nav-intro-pres">
                <img src="images/nav-intro.png" alt="Intro" />
                <span class="cache">
                    Intro
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navigation-pres" id="nav-concep-pres">
                <img src="images/nav-conception.png" alt="Conception" />
                <span class="cache">
                    Conception
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navigation-pres" id="nav-rea-pres">
                <img src="images/nav-realisation.png" alt="Réalisation" />
                <span class="cache">
                    Réalisation
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navigation-pres" id="nav-post-pres">
                <img src="images/nav-post-prod.png" alt="Post-prod" />
                <span class="cache">
                    Post-prod
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="navigation-pres" id="nav-diff-pres">
                <img src="images/nav-diffusion.png" alt="Diffusion" />
                <span class="cache">
                    Diffusion
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content-pres">
        <div id="intro-pres" class="bla-pres"></div>
        <div id="concep-pres" class="bla-pres"></div>
        <div id="rea-pres" class="bla-pres"></div>
        <div id="post-pres" class="bla-pres"></div>
        <div id="diff-pres" class="bla-pres"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery code :

```
   $('#nav-intro-pres').click(function(){
       if($('#intro-pres').css('top','100%')){
           $('#intro-pres').animate({top : '0'});
       } else if($('#intro-pres').css('top','-100%')){
           $('#intro-pres').nextAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '100%'});
           $('#intro-pres').animate({top : '0'});
       }
   });

$('#nav-concep-pres').click(function(){
if($('#concep-pres').css('top','100%')){
    $('#concep-pres').animate({top : '0'});
    $('#concep-pres').prevAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '-100%'});
} else if($('#concep-pres').css('top','-100%')){
    $('#concep-pres').nextAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '100%'});
    $('#concep-pres').animate({top : '0'});
}
});


$('#nav-rea-pres').click(function(){
if($('#rea-pres').css('top','100%')){
    $('#rea-pres').animate({top : '0'});
    $('#rea-pres').prevAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '-100%'});
} else if($('#rea-pres').css('top','-100%')){
    $('#rea-pres').nextAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '100%'});
    $('#rea-pres').animate({top : '0'});
}
});

$('#nav-post-pres').click(function(){
if($('#post-pres').css('top','100%')){
    $('#post-pres').animate({top : '0'});
    $('#post-pres').prevAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '-100%'});
} else if($('#post-pres').css('top','-100%')){
    $('#post-pres').nextAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '100%'});
    $('#post-pres').animate({top : '0'});
}
});


$('#nav-diff-pres').click(function(){
if($('#diff-pres').css('top','100%')){
    $('#diff-pres').animate({top : '0'});
    $('#diff-pres').prevAll('.bla-pres').animate({top : '-100%'});
} else if($('#diff-pres').css('top','-100%')){
    $('#diff-pres').animate({top : '0'});
}
});
```

By deleting the condition `hasClass('on')` everything works...

I know that my code could be reduced, but I don't know how, due to my weakness with jQuery...

Here's the online version, it'll help, I guess :
http://www.maximejimenez.fr/test_insieme/index.html
Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: provide HTML markup and maybe a jsfiddle. Define 'not working'? Any error in console?

Comment: Hi,
Well the animate({top: '-100%'}) doesn't work, but I got no error...
Everything stay to (top: '0px').
I updated the post with the HTML
Thx

Comment: `$('#post-pres').css('top','100%')` returns an object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript.

Comment: Use a flag instead of the css check to toggle the animation

Comment: I don't get it...
$('#my_ID').css() gives #my_ID some style, doesn't it?
You can trust me when I say that I have a poor level in jQuery :p

Comment: @adeneo : what is a flag?

Comment: It's generally a variable that holds a boolean, and you swap that boolean to create toogle functionality.

Comment: @adeneo : I don't kow how to do this :/

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that your `if` statements are not doing what you want them to do.  This statement:

```
if($('#rea-pres').css('top','100%'))
```

will ALWAYS be true because `$('#rea-pres').css('top','100%')` returns a jQuery object which is always truthy.  And, because that is always truthy, you NEVER execute the `else` clause of your `if/else if` statements.

If you are trying to check if the CSS value for `top` is equal to `'100%'`, then you would have to use something like this:

```
if($('#rea-pres').css('top') === '100%')
```

Comment: Ok

But I don't get why
`if($('#rea-pres').css('top','-100%')) `
is working then...

What could be the solution?

Comment: @user2866508 - It will ALWAYS be true also.  See the end of my answer for the proper syntax to check for a particular CSS value.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now, nothing append at all... :/
No error, but no movement

Comment: @user2866508 - then the CSS value is not what you expect it to be.  I'd suggest you put a `console.log($('#rea-pres').css('top'))` statement in, then look in the debug console and see what the actual value is.  Excuse me for saying, but this is basic debugging.  If it doesn't follow the expected code path, then you either insert `console.log()` statements to see what values are and why it's not following the path you want or you set breakpoints and step through the code and watch the variables and the logic flow.  This is basic debugging.

Comment: Ok
Effectively, the value of the css is different than in my comparison.
Maybe could I test it with 0 as referent...
Any tips?

Comment: @user2866508 - in your question you do not describe what you are trying to make the code do so I do not know how to suggest the correct code.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to wind all <div> before the one active and descend  <div> after depending on their position.
(I hope this understandable...)
I tried to test with if($('#my_ID').css('top') > '0'){`' and `if($('#my_ID').css('top') < '0'){`
Now it works for every items but the firt...
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it

```
var pages = ['intro', 'concep', 'rea', 'post', 'diff'],
    speed = 600;

$.each(pages, function(_,page) {
    var nav  = $('#nav-' + page + '-pres'),
        pres = $('#' + page + '-pres');

    if ( ! ( nav.hasClass('on') ) ) {
        nav.on('click', function() {
            var flag = $(this).data('flag');
            pres.animate({ top: 0 }, speed)
                .prevAll('.bla-pres')
                .animate({ top : flag ? '-100%' : '100%'}, speed);

            $(this).data('flag', !flag);
        });
    }
});
```

That's more dynamic and avoids writing the same code over and over. It might need some tweaking to work, as I had nothing to test with.

Comment: This seems to be a better solution than that I wrote
But, I won't be able to tweak it, because of my limited skills...
In this state, it doesn't work...
I think it is because the value of `top` on `$(document).ready` isn't 100% nor -100%
I'm despairing...

Comment: @user2866508 - seems there was an error, try it now and see if it works

Comment: It still doesn't work
It tried to compare with '0' instead of testing with '100%' and '-100%' and it works for all the items but the first (with my code)...
Any idea?